# How do I change an .net Core Validator error message using javascript?

Tags: javascript, validation, asp.net-core

I already have an Required field, e.g.:

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Fixed error message that I don't want")]
    [BindProperty]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And properly added all the validation code required, everything is working OK.

However I'm porting an old asp.net framework to .net core, and the system used to set the error messages on the asp:RequiredFieldValidator using javascript with

```
$("#RequiredFieldValidatorUsername")[0].errormessage = 'some error message';
```

I couldn't find an easy way to set the errormessage from a Required model field by javascript anywhere (I already have the string on the client side).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

e.g.:
The Model class:

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
public string HeaderScript { get; private set; }
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please enter the name")]
[BindProperty]
public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<input ID="TextBoxUserName" asp-for="UserName" />
<span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

I already have a Javscript with the string I want to use on the errormessage, I just need to set it instead of the one in the Model.

Comment: As they're run at completely different times, one server-side, one user-side, you're likely going to need to use `fetch` (JS -> .NET).

Comment: I already have the string on the user side, I just want to change what is displayed, this means that instead of setting the ErrorMessage on the .cs model code I just need to set it by javascript.

I'm not sure how fetch would do this.

Comment: JS cannot interact with the cs model directly. It has to travel via a network request. So `fetch` or similar is needed.

Comment: I don't want or need to interact, I already have the string on the client side, validation already works (both client and server side using jquery.validate), I just want to set a different errormessage by javascript instead of setting it on the Model.

Comment: Then please may you edit the question and include a [mcve]? At the moment it is difficult to discern the issue.

Comment: What I want is to change this ErrorMessage string that's on the UserName:

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Fixed error message that I don't want")]

Using Javascript.

That would be pretty much it. (Editted the question with example but there's really nothing else to it, I just want to change the errormessage...)

Comment: May you share the resulting HTML from `UserName: [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Fixed error message that I don't want")]`?

Comment: This is the html generated:

<input ID="TextBoxUserName" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter the name" name="UserName" value="" />

data-val-required would be what I want to change (hopefully).

Comment: How does the error message get rendered?

Comment: Ah sorry, it's rendered inside the span : <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="UserName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

It's done automatically by jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for `jquery.validate`?

Comment: This worked, but I'm not sure if it has any drawbacks...


 $('#TextBoxUserName').attr('data-val-required', 'my new error message');
 $('form').removeData('validator');
 $('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
 $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('body');

Comment: Glad it worked! Sadly I can’t tell you if your approach has any downsides. It looks ok to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, but I'm not sure if it has any drawbacks...

```
$('#TextBoxUserName').attr('data-val-required', 'my new error message'); 
$('form').removeData('validator');
$('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('body');
```